# git pull --rebase origin tagname?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, git-tag

I'm digging through some production scripts that use git, and trying to make sense of this command:

```
git pull --rebase origin "${tag_or_commit}"
```

From what I'm finding in the documentation for `git pull` and `git rebase`, it looks like the only thing that should **ever** be in that `tag_or_commit` bash variable, would have to be a branch name for the command to work at all.

Is there documented behavior for what this command will do given a tag or commit instead of a branch?  Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: based on your comments on the previous answer, you're just missing one thing: the `git rebase` step rebases the *current branch*, regardless of what arguments you've passed to `git pull`.  You can probably skip all the rest of this!

---

It's actually in [the `git pull` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html), but in typical git documentation fashion, made extra-confusing:

> <refspec> can name an arbitrary remote ref (for example, the name of a tag) or even a collection of refs with corresponding remote-tracking branches (e.g., refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*), but usually it is the name of a branch in the remote repository.

What's missing is a thorough definition of a "refspec" along with a thorough description of the two parts that `git pull` runs.  Unfortunately for the first part, refspecs appear in both fetch and push, but behave differently in them.  It may suffice to say that for fetch purposes, normally you just name a branch or tag that exists on the remote, and `git fetch` copies it to your own repository but changes the name to a remote-tracking branch, such as `origin/master`, *if it's a branch*.  For tags, it leaves the name unchanged.  (More precisely, origin's `refs/heads/master` becomes `refs/remote/origin/master` in your repository, while its `refs/tags/v1.2` stays `refs/tags/v1.2`.)

The second part is perhaps a bit easier: `git pull` collects some flags and acts on them itself, and passes the rest of them to its first step, `git fetch`.  One of the flags `git pull` collects is `--rebase`, which tells it to use `git rebase` as its second step.  Otherwise, it looks to see if it's been configured to use `git rebase` automatically; if not, it defaults to using `git merge`.

In this case, then, given a tag name *`tag`*, `git pull` will:<sup>1</sup>

1. run `git fetch origin tag`
2. run `git rebase tag`

The fetch step will create a local tag if needed, fetching any corresponding commits and other objects if needed, or just be a glorified no-op if you already have the tag.

The second step is the especially-confusing bit.  Passing a tag name to `git rebase` as its "upstream" argument seems weird.  It is, however, well-defined and can make sense; and this is also described reasonably well in [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), provided you know the secret about rebase: it doesn't *change* any commits, it just *copies* some commits, then re-points your current branch.

First, git gets a list of commits that are contained within the current branch,<sup>2</sup> excluding any commits reachable from the named upstream:

```
$ git rev-list tag..HEAD
```

Next, git gets onto a new anonymous branch starting with the commit identified by the `--onto` argument, or if there is no `--onto`, the commit identified by the "upstream" argument.  In this case there is no `--onto` and the "upstream" argument is a tag, so git could simply check out the tag (it doesn't quite—it uses a general form that works for branch names as well—but it works out the same).

As its second to last step, the rebase "replays" each of the commits whose IDs are in the `git rev-list` output.  Essentially, git cherry-picks each such commit into the new anonymous branch.

As the final step (if all has gone well, or after you've fixed things up and done `git rebase --continue`), git moves the branch you were on<sup>3</sup> to point to the final commit made by coping all the to-be-copied commits.  Assuming you were on a branch that originates somewhere "before" the tagged commit `T`, we can thus draw a graph of the final result like this:

```
    A - B - C            [abandoned]
  /
o - o - T - o - o         <-- somebranch
          \
           A' - B' - C'   <-- HEAD=yourbranch
```

Here `A` through `C` are your original commits that were on `yourbranch` before the `git pull origin tag` step, and `A'` through `C'` are their copies.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is still simplified, and `git pull` has evolved over time; the actual arguments can get pretty complex.  None of that matters for this particular case, fortunately.

<sup>2</sup>This even works if you're on no branch at all: in that case git uses the anonymous branch defined by whatever commit-ID is in `HEAD`.

<sup>3</sup>If you were not on a branch, that's even easier: it just skips this step entirely.  `HEAD` still points to an anonymous branch, but now it's the copied one.

Comment: Your edit is very helpful.  But what if I've just checked out that tag, so my HEAD is detached?

Comment: If you're on a detached HEAD, git still does the "copy commits" step.  To see what commits get copied, use that `git rev-list` command.  If the detached HEAD points to the same commit as the tag, the output from `git rev-list` will be empty, so git will copy no commits: another glorified no-op.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like it actually fails given simply a tagname, but succeeds given `tags/tagname`.  Otherwise the `git fetch origin tagname` returns "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref tagname".

Comment: Interesting; it (git fetch) is supposed to auto-detect tag names and match them up.  Or was, at one point. I'm not a fan of as much "do what I meant, not what I entered as a command" magic as others myself so I hesitate to call it a bug :-)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in git at all.  It's a hell of a bug in the production script I was reading through, though.  I finally got furious and just finished rewriting the whole thing with proper code refactoring and correct use of git commands.  Thanks for your help in clarifying my understanding of the commands.  :)

Answer (score 2):

A tag and branch are really just references to commits, with the main difference being a branch refers to a moving target (the latest commit on that branch), while a tag references a single point in time commit, but ultimately they are just pointing to a commit.

The `tag_or_commit` variable above could be renamed `tag_or_branch_or_commit`, or simply `commit`. I would argue that the variable name is somewhat misleading / confusing.

I find the most common usage of rebasing it to give a branch, which means to rebase the branch to the most recent commit. Providing a commit (or tag) will rebase up to that commit, and no further.

So the full command above is pulling from the origin, and then rebasing the commits that have happened up to the point that `tag_or_commit` is referring to. A use case might be if you wanted to rebase to what's been released to production, and you have a tag `production_release`, then if you were to execute:

`git pull --rebase origin production_release`

You would get all the commits up until the `production_release` tag, but no more.

Comment: I'm aware of the relation between tags, branches, and commits, but how exactly can you rebase a tag?  I thought tags were immutable.  Or would this command automatically update `.git/refs/tags/tagname` after building the appropriate new commits?  (That can't be right....)

Comment: The tag is just a reference to a commit, so think of it getting replaced with the SHA of the commit it refers to in the command above.

Comment: Basically, you are rebasing up to the commit that the tag references

Comment: I'm still not getting it.  I understand the `fetch` part of what this command does...could you please tell me what the equivalent `git rebase` command would be?  Because the way I'm reading `man git-rebase`, if called without `--onto`, the first arg is `<upstream>` and the second is `<branch>`—that's an actual branch, not a commit-ish.

Comment: The equivalient git rebase command would be `git rebase "${tag_or_commit}"` The <branch> as specified in the docs can be replaced with the SHA of a commit.